# Seeing how often a specific subpage is viewed with Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

We are using a link schema like this: `website.com/<location>/<product>`
While it's really easy to check with GA which location is the one with the most pageviews (just make a report that's filtered by a simple match), I want to view which products are the most viewed, e.g. showing up similiar to this:
`/*/product1 - 1000 Views`
`/*/product2 - 500 Views`
`/*/product3 - 300 Views`

Is there a way to do this with Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your products have a same prefix you can perform a simple filter like this:

```
\/.*\/product
```

However, if your products name is different you have to create a regex to exclude everyone based only of its name (suboptimal solution because you should consider all product names).

Therefore the best solution is to export the data to Excel or Spreadsheet and process them afterwards by removing the main folder and add together the views of the products with the same name (if they can be present in different categories).